# TypeError: Object <Object> has no method 'query' with node pg library

Tags: node.js, postgresql

When I fetch the records from Db it shows the below error.

> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'query'

I created the DB configuration on separate file in the name as dbConfig.js and used it on another file. It looks likes below:

In dbConfig.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://pgadmin:e100095@localhost:5432/searchtest";

var dbClient = new pg.Client(conString);
//dbClient=dbClient.connect();
dbClient.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
});
```

the record fetching query is :

```
var configDB= require('../dbConfig');

var query = configDB.query("SELECT * FROM resource_url where id = "+indexID,function(err,result){
    if(err){console.log("Error : "+err);}
    else {colsole.log("results");}
});
```

Comment: Do you actually export anything from dbConfig.js? As in do you do `module.exports = dbClient;` ?

Comment: Also, do **NOT** use string string concatenation with `+` to build your query. Always use interpolation as mentioned in the docs https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#parameterized-query-with-config-object That's half the point of using a database driver library ;)

Comment: @AndyRay, yes iIhave export it using router.dbClient

Comment: And also modified the query like : **var query = configDB.query("SELECT * FROM resource_url where id = $1",[indexID]** but still it remains the same error. Coult you suggest me the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your code:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var dbClient = new pg.Client(conString);
```

change:

```
var pg       = require('pg').Client;
var dbClient = new pg(conString);
```

And **conString**, you also use as below:

```
var conString                       = {
    user                : 'my_user',
    password            : 'my_pass',
    database            : 'my_database',
    host                : 'my_host', // example abc.com
    port                : my_port
};
```

Comment: thanks for your response.When I changed this code I face **ReferenceError: Client is not defined
** Error

Comment: Sorry, I editted for "Client" variable. "Client" is "pg" in your code. You can see code for editting of me.

Comment: thanks for ur response I already try this too it remains the same error.

Comment: Code for testing: http://www.mediafire.com/download/atdj09ham07e8d9/Test.zip

You need to edit for MyServer.js file about your server information. And then running for testing, if connection is successfull, you can editting your code as code sample.